# Verbs with interchanged subject and object

Tags: verbs, synonyms, terminology, antonyms

For some verbs we can find another (not necessarily unique) verb which has the same meaning except that it corresponds the subject and the object in the opposite direction.  For example, if I say “our group *comprises* 10 people”, the same can be expressed by saying that “10 people *constitute* our group”.

How do linguists refer to such pairs of “opposite” verbs, and how do I find them (except maybe by searching for dictionary definitions that begin with “to be”)?

Comment: Can you give one or two more examples of such '_inverted synonyms_'? It is unlikely that there will be a specific term for a group of words that comprise only a very small number of members. There is, however, a quite a large group of verbs which license an inversion (or interchange) so that the object becomes the subject (and the original subject is omitted). For example: _She is cooking the pasta >> The pasta is cooking - They began the game >> The game began._ These are called _'ergative verbs'_  https://www.thoughtco.com/ergative-grammar-term-1690608).

Comment: @Shoe ***Comprise*** can be regarded as such an "ergative verb". OED sense 8 of *comprise* provides examples, the equivalent of "10 people comprise our group". *1969   W. Hooper in C. S. Lewis Sel. Lit. Ess. p. xix   These essays together with those contained in this volume comprise the total of C. S. Lewis's essays on literature. 1969   N. Perrin Dr. Bowdler's Legacy (1970) i. 20   As to who comprised this new reading public, Jeffrey..guessed in 1812 that there were 20,000 upper-class readers in Great Britain.*

Comment: Consider 1) “He _fears_ nothing.” vs. “Nothing _scares_ him.”, 2) “People _ride_ horses.” vs. “Horses _carry_ people.”, 3) “He _orders_ the whole troop.” vs. “The whole troop _obeys_ him.”, 4) “Everyone in the lab _contracted_ the virus.” vs. “The virus _infected_ everyone in the lab.”, or 5) “The family _caught_ a mysterious disease.” vs. “A mysterious diease _hit_ the family.”  @Shoe

Comment: Thanks for the examples. _Comprise/constitute_ seem to me to be in a different category than loose antonyms such as _ride/carry_, _contract/infect_, _caught/hit_, etc. But I too would be interested to know if there is a specific term for this linguistic feature.

Comment: Gee, I didn’t know these were actually antonyms.  A bit of googling led me to [“relational antonyms”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_%28semantics%29#Relational_antonyms) which are [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_%29semantics%29) as “pairs of words that refer to a relationship from opposite points of view”.  I guess the verb pairs I gave (including (comprise, constitute)) could be considered a special case thereof, no?

Comment: I don't think that _comprise_ and _constitute_ can be considered relational antonyms. In fact, I'm hard-pressed to think of any sensible antonym of _comprise_ (maybe _exclude_). _Comprise_ is an odd word in that you will find it in both _whole/parts_ and _parts/whole_ constructions_: _The team comprises seven players_ and _Seven players comprise the team_.

Comment: Based on what has unfolded here, it seems like comprise/constitute could be called "relational synonyms" unlike those other "relational antonym" verbs (ride/carry, orders/obeys)